# функция заполнения двумерного массива в С

Tags: c

есть функция заполнения значений элементов двумерного массива, после первого ввода элемента программа крашится

вот весь код программы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void setMatrixValues(int lineSize, int columnSize, int **matrix);
void printMatrix(int lineSize, int columnSize, int **matrix);
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int M, N;
    int **ptr_matrix;
    printf("Введите кол-во строк матрицы: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы: ");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    int matrix[N][M];
    ptr_matrix = matrix[N][M];

    //заполнение
    setMatrixValues(N, M, ptr_matrix);
    //вывод
    printMatrix(N, M, ptr_matrix);


    return 0;
}


void printMatrix(int lineSize, int columnSize, int **matrix){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < lineSize; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < columnSize; j++){
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

void setMatrixValues(int lineSize, int columnSize, int **matrix){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < lineSize; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < columnSize; j++){
            printf("Введите значение элемента [%d][%d]: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В этой строке нет смысла: `ptr_matrix = matrix[N][M];` Тут то она и крашится. Во-первых, массивы индексируются с нуля, а значит, чтобы обратиться к последнему элементу матрицы, вам надо написать `matrix[N-1][M-1]`. Во-вторых, в чём смысл указателю на указатель на `int` присваивать 'int' как значение, указатель же хранит адрес в памяти, а не самое целое число'.

Comment: Какой это язык, С или С++?

Comment: C
*набрал 15 симв для комментария*

Comment: так снимите метку, что плюсы

Comment: исправил 23 строку
ptr_matrix = &matrix;
теперь все норм работает

Comment: Не самое лучшее решение. У меня это крашится, например.

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта строка:

```
ptr_matrix = matrix[N][M];
```

не имеет смысла, как правильно заметили в комментариях.

Во-первых, `matrix[N][M]` - это обращение к несуществующему элементу матрицы (индексы вне диапазона). А потом вы пытаетесь присвоить получившийся `int` указателю типа `int **`. Так делать нельзя, и тут должна быть ошибка компиляции. Если ее нет, стоит включить в настройках компилятора более строгие ошибки.

Можно было бы попробовать написать `ptr_matrix = matrix;`, но это тоже вызовет ошибку. Массив `matrix` (типа `int [N][M]`) здесь автоматически преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент (на первый одномерный подмассив) типа `int (*)[M]` ("указатель на массив размера `M`"). Такой указатель нельзя преобразовать в `int **`, ведь это указатели на совершенно разные типы.

Правильное решение, на самом деле, очень простое:

Уберите `int **ptr_matrix;` и передавайте `matrix` напрямую в функции, и замените параметры `int **matrix` на `int matrix[lineSize][columnSize]`.

Вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void setMatrixValues(int lineSize, int columnSize, int matrix[lineSize][columnSize]);
void printMatrix(int lineSize, int columnSize, int matrix[lineSize][columnSize]);
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int M, N;

    printf("Введите кол-во строк матрицы: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы: ");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    int matrix[N][M];

    //заполнение
    setMatrixValues(N, M, matrix);
    //вывод
    printMatrix(N, M, matrix);


    return 0;
}


void printMatrix(int lineSize, int columnSize, int matrix[lineSize][columnSize]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < lineSize; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < columnSize; j++){
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

void setMatrixValues(int lineSize, int columnSize, int matrix[lineSize][columnSize]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < lineSize; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < columnSize; j++){
            printf("Введите значение элемента [%d][%d]: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

> исправил 23 строку ptr_matrix = &matrix; теперь все норм работает

Тут тоже должна быть ошибка о недопустимом преобразовании между указателями разных типов.

Даже если компилятор дает вам выполнить такое присваивание (или если вы поставите каст, чтобы по-честному убрать это ошибку: `ptr_matrix = (int**)&matrix;`), то после этого ваша программа работает по чистой случайности, из-за какой-то особенности компилятора. На моей машине это вызывает краш.

Comment: если убрать ptr_matrix и передавать в функцию напрямую matrix, то после первого же ввода элемента программа крашится

Comment: @ДотерыНелюди Вы параметры функций на `int matrix[lineSize][columnSize]` заменили?

Comment: Можете прикрепить пример кода? А то мне самому непонятно, как вы в параметрах функции напишите `int matrice[lineSize][columnSize]`.

Comment: @MatveyKiselyov Прикрепил.

Comment: `void fillMatrix(int lineSize, int columnSize, int matrix[lineSize][columnSize]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < lineSize; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < columnSize; j++){
            printf("Введите значение элемента [%d][%d]: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @ДотерыНелюди Код, который я добавил в ответ, у вас не работает?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat работает, ищу где в моем коде все таки ошибки